# Rename pictures in iPhoto

Tags: photos.app, macos

What's the best way for renaming all the pictures of an event or an album in iPhoto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was easy:

1. Select all the pictures
2. Menu Photos -> Batch Change...

Comment: Please mark this response as an answer.

Comment: @Matt, I have to wait 21 hours :)

Comment: Ah. My apologies. Some people nowadays... :P